# Do I need to use session.Flush for delete?

Tags: nhibernate

I want to send an email first. If it doesn't succeed, I delete from the database.

Here's my code

```
        if (EmailAllPosts)
            emailStatus = ProcessEmailAllPosts(userAlert, 
            emailModel, ps, defaultAdminEmail, fileURL);

        if ((alertType == (int)Defines.AlertType.Email) && !emailStatus)
        {
            session.Delete(userAlert);
        }
        else
        {
            userAlert.IsAlertSent = true;
            session.Update(userAlert);
        }
        session.Flush();
```

Do I need to use session.Flush for delete?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your FlushMode.

With Never, you need to issue the flush yourself.

With Auto, NHibernate will take care of that stuff, i.e. before commit the transaction or when you ask it to query the database for something.

With Commit, NHibernate will flush on commit. No commit, no flush.

Comment: Nice answer. The delete is the API method of the ISession. It has nothing with SQL DELETE statement. Unless session is Flushed, the SQL DELETE is never executed

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you use sessions properly (that means: for a single operation, in a single thread, fetching all the data used in the same session, with explicit transaction commited at the end) - **no**. There's no need to call `Flush` or even `Update` in that case - NHibernate by default flushes all the changes to the database before transaction commit or before querying for possibly related data.